# How to separate data in a text box with a separator

Tags: c#, .net, math, textbox, integer

With this problem I have, I'm trying to separate data in a textbox, so the user could input something like this:

```
100,65,21,53,51,100,69
```

And it would return this:

```
100
65
21
53
51
100
69
```

And I would be able to parse these and use them in a mathematical equation? Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Use String.Split() method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Split() method.

```
string example = "waw,numb";
string[] exampleSplitted = example.Split(',');
```

that way example splitted would be an array with the string separated into arrays items.

```
for(int i = 0;i<2;i++)
{
WriteLine(exampleSplitted[i]);
}
```

Output

```
waw
numb
```

if you want the results as integers just use [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but be careful when parsing strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "100,65,21,53,51,100,69";
        var splitText = text.Split(',').ToArray();
        int[] intArray = new int[splitText.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in splitText)
        {
            intArray[i] = int.Parse(item);
            i++;

        }
        //use intArray for your mathamatical calculations
        //you can check splitText is null for validations
```